# removing the highlighted selected segment

Tags: swift, uikit, uisegmentedcontrol

can u guys tell me how to remove that highlight it has? i cant find a way to do it.

this is how it is working:

[image: one]
[image: two]

Comment: This seems to directly related to your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75697724/style-my-segmentedcontrol-with-an-underline-only). Why not update that one instead of posting a new question?

Comment: but i have 2 segments

Comment: Don't you have in consoles logs with constraints errors?

Comment: Instead of posting an image of the console text, please copy and paste the actual text into the question. Makes it easier to read and search.

Comment: From what I guess, you are adding each time new constraints. You should instead keep them, and activate/deactivate the one needed.

Comment: how should i do it do you have an idea?

Comment: @FábioGalante - the code you posted uses, for example: `self.bottomAnchor` ... does that mean you have the segmented control embedded as a subview of a custom view?

Comment: @FábioGalante - and, do you want the "underline" to animate with the highlight?

Comment: @DonMag yes i would like to have an animation and yes i have the segmented control as a subview

Comment: Side note ``sender.self.selectedSegmentIndex` might just be `sender.selectedSegmentIndex`, not need for `self` here

Comment: ok i will try using that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I commented when you posted about this previously - heading over to Google (or your favorite search engine) and searching along the lines of `swift custom uisegmentedcontrol` ... returns many, many examples, discussions, tutorials, etc. You could almost certainly find a pre-built one.

It appears you want a segmented control with ***only*** an underline -- no borders or highlight or separator line at all.

However, here is a quick, very simple example that looks like what you're trying to do.

We'll create a custom view class, with an embedded `UISegmentedControl` and an "underline" view. This gives us all the advantages of the `UISegmentedControl` without messing with its internal view structure:

```
class MyCustomSegmentedControlView: UIView {
    
    public var underlineColor: UIColor = .black {
        didSet { underlineView.backgroundColor = underlineColor }
    }
    
    public let segCtrl = UISegmentedControl()
    
    public func setSegmentTitles(_ titles: [String]) {
        segCtrl.removeAllSegments()
        titles.reversed().forEach { str in
            segCtrl.insertSegment(withTitle: str, at: 0, animated: false)
        }
        segCtrl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
        moveUnderline(animated: false)
    }
    
    private let underlineView = UIView()
    private var segCtrlCurrentSize: CGSize = .zero

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        
        segCtrl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(segCtrl)
        addSubview(underlineView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            segCtrl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            segCtrl.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            segCtrl.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            segCtrl.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
        ])
        
        underlineView.backgroundColor = underlineColor

        // this will "remove" the highlight frame
        //  not really remove... just make it clear
        segCtrl.selectedSegmentTintColor = .clear
        
        segCtrl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(segChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    }
    
    @objc func segChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        moveUnderline(animated: true)
    }
    
    private func moveUnderline(animated: Bool) {
        // make sure selectedSegmentIndex is valid
        //  if not, hide the underline view
        guard segCtrl.selectedSegmentIndex > -1,
              segCtrl.selectedSegmentIndex < segCtrl.numberOfSegments
        else {
            underlineView.isHidden = true
            return
        }
        underlineView.isHidden = false
        // put the underline view at the bottom of the selected segment
        //  same width as the segment, 2-points height
        var r = segCtrl.subviews[segCtrl.selectedSegmentIndex].frame
        r.origin.y = r.height - 2.0
        r.size.height = 2.0
        if animated {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                self.underlineView.frame = r
            })
        } else {
            self.underlineView.frame = r
        }
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        // if the segmented control frame has changed
        if segCtrlCurrentSize != segCtrl.frame.size {
            segCtrlCurrentSize = segCtrl.frame.size
            
            // background and divider images are stretched
            //  horizontally / vertically respectively
            // so we can use a single 1 x controlHeight image for both
            let sz: CGSize = .init(width: 1.0, height: segCtrlCurrentSize.height)
            var img = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: sz).image { rendererContext in
                UIColor.white.setFill()
                rendererContext.fill(CGRect(origin: .zero, size: sz))
            }
            segCtrl.setBackgroundImage(img, for: [], barMetrics: .default)
            segCtrl.setDividerImage(img, forLeftSegmentState: .selected, rightSegmentState: .normal, barMetrics: .default)
            
            moveUnderline(animated: false)
        }
    }
}
```

and asimple example controller class:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let mySeg = MyCustomSegmentedControlView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        mySeg.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(mySeg)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            mySeg.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            mySeg.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            mySeg.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            // no height or bottom - it will use the segmented control's intrinsic height
        ])
        
        mySeg.setSegmentTitles(["Cart", "Wishlist"])
        mySeg.underlineColor = .orange
        
        // we could use:
        //  protocol/delegate pattern, or
        //  closure
        // for simplicity, we'll add another target to the segmented control
        mySeg.segCtrl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(segChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    }
    
    @objc func segChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        print("Seg Control Changed to:", sender.selectedSegmentIndex)
    }

}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

Note that it will also work with more than 2 segments.